# how to show 4 recent blog post in a horizontal way in my static homepage wordpress custom loop

Tags: wordpress

actually im creating a eCommerce website i want to show my 4 recent blog post in my static home page and blog post shld be in a horizontal way i tried several ways couldnt get it 
i want my blog post to shoe title picture and little information abt it

```
function Last5posts()
{
    $args = array( "showposts" => 5 );                  
    query_posts($args);

    $content = "";

    if( have_posts() ) : 

        while( have_posts() ) :

            the_post();
            $link = get_permalink();
            $title = get_the_title();
            $date = get_the_date();  
            $thumbnails =get_the_post_thumbnail();  
          $excerpt= get_the_excerpt();               



  $content .= "<div style='padding: 5px; float:left;  height:250px;
    width:250px; margin-right:5px; border: 1px solid red'>";
            $content .= "<h3><a href='$link' target='_top'>$title / $date / 

$thumbnails</a></h3>\n";
            $content .= "<p class='excerpt'>" . get_the_excerpt() . "</p>";
            $content .= "</div>";


        endwhile;

        wp_reset_query();

    endif;

    // Leave one line commented out depending on usage
    echo $content;   // For use as widget
    //return $content; // for use as shortcode
}
add_shortcode('Last5Posts', 'Last5posts' );
```

Comment: Horizontal way? You might want to look CSS. float:left; set size like width:80px; height:100px;

Comment: could u help me with the code pls  @craftein

Comment: i tried but the title going out of box and even the excerpt

Answer (score 0):

Here's a guide, an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/SWCAz/1/) that you could follow.

Let's say your `div` containers have a class `.hor-con`.

Then we give them a style of:

```
.hor-con {
    float:left;
    height:250px;
    width:250px;
    margin-right:5px;
}
```

Comment: i tried it workds but the title is going out of the boxx

Comment: of course you have to change some value(s) yourself. i don't even know how long are your titles. you did not even provide us some sample data. i also don't even know the max width of your page layout. -- just change the width which suits you and your design.